# Correct way to get results from a blocking collection

Tags: c#, blockingcollection

I have 50 IMountCmd objects from one or more threads and drop them in a blocking collection.  Each is executed and some get results or errors.  They are put into a ConcurrentDictionary where I loop for ContainsKey and return the objects.  Does this seems thread safe and correct way to process a blocking queue?

```
public class CmdGetAxisDegrees : IMountCommand
{
    public long Id { get; }
    public DateTime CreatedUtc { get; private set; }
    public bool Successful { get; private set; }
    public Exception Exception { get; private set; }
    public dynamic Result { get; private set; }
    private readonly AxisId _axis;

    public CmdGetAxisDegrees(long id, AxisId axis)
    {
        Id = id;
        _axis = axis;
        CreatedUtc = HiResDateTime.UtcNow;
        Successful = false;
        Queues.AddCommand(this);
    }

    public void Execute(Actions actions)
    {
        try
        {
            Result = actions.GetAxisDegrees(_axis);
            Successful = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Successful = false;
            Exception = e;
        }
    }
}

 private static void ProcessCommandQueue(IMountCommand command)
    {
        command.Execute(_actions);
        if (command.Id > 0)
        {
            _resultsDictionary.TryAdd(command.Id, command);
        }
    }

public static IMountCommand GetCommandResult(long id)
    {
        IMountCommand result;
        while (true)
        {
            if (!_resultsDictionary.ContainsKey(id)) continue;
            var success = _resultsDictionary.TryRemove(id, out result);
            if (!success)
            {
                //log 
            }
            break;
        }
        return result;
    }

  static Queues()
    {
        _actions = new Actions();
        _resultsDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<long, IMountCommand>();
        _commandBlockingCollection = new BlockingCollection<IMountCommand>();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            foreach (var command in _commandBlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                ProcessCommandQueue(command);
            }
        });
    }

public interface IMountCommand
{
    long Id { get; }
    DateTime CreatedUtc { get; }
    bool Successful { get; }
    Exception Exception { get; }
    dynamic Result { get; }
    void Execute(Actions actions);
}
```

Comment: What is IMountCommand? What is Queues, I don't see this defined anywhere?

Comment: Use of `ConcurrentQueue` implies an intent for this to be thread safe, although it's not 100% clear. From that standpoint, use of class-level fields is likely to cause problems. If a class instance is handling multiple method calls simultaneously then the values of those fields could change unpredictably, even while they're being used. To the extent possible it would be better to replace then with variables created within methods, and then the output is the return value of the method instead of setting a field.

Comment: Class instances of IMountCommand are created each time- no reuse.